# How to set an environment variable in Ubuntu and Windows and store it securely?

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, laravel-4, environment-variables

I am working on an application based on laravel. I need to set my database password in the config so that laravel can use it to connect to the database.

Now I have two problems:
1) I don't want to set password for every other local environment I use.
2) I don't want to set the password in the config file because when I share the code with my team members on git, they can view my password.

I may have figured out a way around this which is to store the password in an environment variable and then use the getenv() PHP function to retrieve it in the config file. So now I can just set the environment variable in any number of environments and the code in the config file will remain the same, and also the other members won't be able to see my password.

Now I don't know how to set environment variables, and other stuff like global/local environment variables and temporary/persistent variables.

And if I am storing the password in the environment variables, should I hash these passwords? Will they be accessible to other users who log onto my machine?
And if I do hash them and store them, how am i supposed to use them in the config file?

Is there a different, a more ideal way around my problem?

Comment: Why do you not use a second local config file that contains the password and is not put into source code control? (Then your collaborators will have to create their own such file.) If you set an environment variable the code for this has to be stored in some file, right? How do you plan to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Laravel Way**

Laravel uses `.env.php` files to solve this for you: http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#protecting-sensitive-configuration. But as you still need to set the environment in your start.php file, I prefer to do it differenlty:

**My Way**

I create a `.environment` file in my app root folder with things like:

```
<?php

return [

    'LARAVEL_ENV' => 'development',

    'DOMAIN' => 'myapp.com',

    'DEBUG_MODE' => true,

    'MAIN.DATABASE_HOST' => 'localhost',
    'MAIN.DATABASE_NAME' => 'databasename',
    'MAIN.DATABASE_USER' => 'myusername',
    'MAIN.DATABASE_PASSWORD' => 'basswort',

];
```

I have a class to load the environment file:

```
<?php

namespace PragmaRX\Support;

use Exception;

class Environment {

    protected static $loaded = false;

    public static function load($file = null)
    {
        if ( ! static::$loaded)
        {
            if ( ! file_exists($file))
            {
                throw new Exception('Environment file (.environment) was not set or does not exists: '.$file);
            }

            foreach(require $file as $key => $value)
            {
                if ($value === false)
                {
                    $value = '(false)';
                }
                else
                if ($value === null)
                {
                    $value = '(null)';
                }
                else
                if (empty($value))
                {
                    $value = '(empty)';
                }

                putenv(sprintf('%s=%s', $key, $value));
            }

            static::$loaded = true;
        }
    }

    public static function getDetectionClosure($file = null)
    {
        static::load($file);

        return function() { return getenv('LARAVEL_ENV'); };
    }
}
```

Then in my app/bootstrap/start.php I just need to load it this way:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(
    \App\Environment::getDetectionClosure(__DIR__.'/../.environment')
);
```

As you can see, the closure will return the current LARAVEL_ENV, stored in my .environment file. But it also will load all keys to the PHP environment, so, now, in my application I just need to

```
<?php

return [

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    'default' => 'main',

    'connections' => [

        'main' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => getenv('MAIN.DATABASE_HOST'),
            'database' => getenv('MAIN.DATABASE_NAME'),
            'username' => getenv('MAIN.DATABASE_USER'),
            'password' => getenv('MAIN.DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

    ],

];
```

Add the `.environment` file to your gitignore file and you should be safe, but you'll have to, of course, create (or copy and edit) the file every time you set a new server.

**About Security**

Everything in your system is a file, you are protected if your files are protected. It's that simple. A VirtualHost file is a file accessible by your webserver, if someone hacks your webserver you'll have not only your .environment file exposed, but also your VirtualHost one, so IMO you're not securer using one or another.

Comment: Should I also encrypt the password in the .env.php file and then decrypt it in the config file?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary, but yes, you get a little more securer doing it this way. In my opinion, completely different passwords, for everything we use, are better than any other obfuscation we might think of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on security by any means but I think you should avoid trying to do what you want to do and just define your environments. If you really want to set an environmental variable this is how you do it in **Ubuntu**:

In your `vhost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv APP_ENV "test"
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I assume Windows is your client machine?

Comment: I use both Ubuntu and Windows. I have cloned the repository on both the machines.

Answer (score 0):

There are many good answers already, but as a side note. You can include your DB config file in .gitignore so it won't be shared among the development team by git. Something like config.php.orig in the project files and your own copy config.php listed in .gitignore should do the trick.